# Is it possible to mmap the network-adapter's DMA region into userspace?

Tags: c, network-programming, linux-device-driver, userspace

How do you find the DMA address of the network-adapter, then is it possible to mmap that address and then read and write to it?

Comment: Are you writing a kernel-space device driver, or a user-space program?  The answer is different depending on which it is.

Comment: You might want to look at PACKET_MMAP: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt.  It might be helpful to explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I suspect _Jim D_ is on to something. Which makes this question an XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem What you _probably_ want to do is map the _kernel_ socket buffers into userspace to achieve some "zero copy" or "kernel bypass" That is what `PACKET_MMAP` is for. Trying to map the controller into userspace to feed it raw commands is not the way to achieve that (e.g. How would you field an interrupt?)

Comment: Have you checked DPDK (https://www.dpdk.org/about/)?

Comment: Good point -- I've glanced at DPDK, and I've written AF_XDP, however it requires an upgraded kernel on most systems and DRV mode might not be supported -- and I suppose PACKET_MMAP is the goal then, TX wasn't working for V3, what do you think about SKB-mode AF_XDP vs PACKET_MMAP?